# Get WPF user controls events after saving to a XAML file and restoring

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am new to WPF. I have Created some user Controls with some basic events, then loaded these user controls at runtime in a listview. Then I dragged and dropped these user controls on a container (Canvas). 
Then I tried to store it using the `XamlWriter.Save` function and to reopen it with `XamlReader.Load`. So far so good.

The problem is that I am not getting the events when I reopened the stored XAML.
I have reads in Microsoft blogs that storing events using `XamlWriter.Save` is not possible. My goal is to get the events when I restore the XAML again. How can I do this?

Comment: do your Usercontrols expose same events? or events vary depending on controls

Comment: Events varies depends upon the user control.

Comment: Didn't you answer yourself when you said "...storing events using XamlWriter.Save is not possible."  Why are you doing this?  There may be a better way to accomplish what you're trying to do.

Comment: You are right Robaticus, Please tell me the another better way to accomplish what asked for. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a reason you are serializing to/from xaml?  Is dynamically loading xaml at runtime a requirement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If serializing to and from xaml is not actually a requirement then you may want to change your strategy.  Normally in WPF you want to avoid lists of controls and instead have a list of data, then template that data so that it shows up as different controls.  Try binding your ListView to a collection of objects that simply represent data, and then create templates to render your controls.  Your problem might be similar to the one in this question: [WPF Custom control for receipt preview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10416705/wpf-custom-control-for-receipt-preview/10417812#10417812)